# jQuery: datepicker alternative

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a better, smaller alternative to the jQuery datepicker?
The ui.datepicker.js has app. 70kb which is pretty huge imo.
Could it be compressed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need the whole ui library just http://jqueryui.com/download disable the other stuff or you can use google ajax api cdn. the best alternative to jui datepicker is the html5 datepicker with is only supported by opera so far `<input type="datetime-local" />`

Comment: +1 for HTML5 date-picker. Can't wait to see it in all browsers.

Comment: You guys got my hopes up, but unfortunately almost 2 years later, [Opera is still the only browser](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus) that supports HTML5 date forms.  I'm not going to hold my breath

Answer (score 6):

The best alternative I know is [Kelvin luck's datepicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/).

Answer (score 6):

It's not smaller in terms of file size, but arguably "better" is the [Any+Time™ DatePicker/TimePicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/), which is probably the fastest, easiest and most feature-laden date/time picker available.  It supports countless formats, custom labels & styles, jQuery UI themes, keyboard accessibility and even time zones!  And best of all, it's free under the CC-BY-NC-SA license.

Comment: The license says: "NonCommercial — You may not use the material for commercial purposes."

Comment: You can use the picker on websites that sell other things, but you can't sell the picker or use it on pages that require payment to access. If you want to sell the code or sell access to it, you can purchase a commercial license.

Comment: You still need jquery. So not an alternative then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that: [Alternate Date Picker](http://review.dev64.net/dp/) - completely different approach - more like proof of concept, then actual solution.