# jQuery UI Datepicker Slow During Typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, performance

I've heard all these great experiences of how great and elegant jQuery is, but I'm 0 for 2 trying to implement jQuery controls in real world projects due to poor performance.  I am running into a similar problem as [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991439/jquery-ui-datepicker-performance) this time.  The jQuery UI DatePicker failed User Acceptance Testing in an ASP.NET application I'm working on because while typing in the textbox, there is some lag specifically when entering in the last two numbers.  (e.g. '1/1/20**10**').

Does anyone know of an option/approach that would stop jQuery UI from interfering with the user's typing in the textbox that it's tied to?

Comment: Just tried this on the jquery ui demo page. No issues at all.
Can you recreate this issue? Have you got any video demonstrating the problem, any facts / figures, also which browsers, what was the spec of the pc....etc etc, what other js was running on the page, how many other controls...We really need more info.

Comment: As redsquare said - have you tried the jQuery UI demo on the jQuery website? If you don't have problems there, then there may be something very specific with your site.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm experiencing the exact issue, and I have the same problem on the jQueryUI demo site as well.

Comment: I'm seeing this now too.  It wasn't always like this, I wonder what changed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue in IE 6.
I used a performance tool (DynaTrace Ajax Edition) to see where was the lag and I found it in the update date function performed on a keyup event.
So, my work around has been to deactivate the keyup event.

```
$( "#idOfTheInput" ).unbind("keyup");
```

**EDIT:** There is a drawback of doing this. When typing manually the date, the datepicker will not be refreshed.

So, another (better?) solution is to show the date picker only when the user clicks on the little button with the option `showOn: 'button'` (more info here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger )

Then, change the JQuery datepicker code to refresh the date only when the date picker is shown. To do that find the `_doKeyUp` function and add a condition saying "if the date picker is shown, do your update, otherwise do not refresh".

```
_doKeyUp: function(event) {
    var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(event.target);
    if ($.datepicker._datepickerShowing) {
        if (inst.input.val() != inst.lastVal) {
            try {
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._get(inst, 'dateFormat'),
                    (inst.input ? inst.input.val() : null),
                    $.datepicker._getFormatConfig(inst));
                if (date) { // only if valid
                    $.datepicker._setDateFromField(inst);
                    $.datepicker._updateAlternate(inst);
                    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker(inst);
                }
            }
            catch (event) {
                $.datepicker.log(event);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
},
```

Of course, it is a bit nasty to change the code of the plugin...

Comment: Awesome, would you mind sharing the tool you used?  I can't wait to test this out next week.

Comment: I used DynaTrace Ajax. Basically, this software trace everything between you and the server: network, cache, javascript and Ajax. I don't like to advertise but it is an amazing program. Very helpful.

Comment: Sorry took me so long, I couldn't reproduce the problem in IE 9.  So, I went back and sure enough IE 7 still lags.  Used your fix and problem vanished.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what Jason said, you can override the method outside the base ui file by doing this

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery.datepicker._doKeyUp = function(event) {
    var inst = jQuery.datepicker._getInst(event.target);
    if(jQuery.datepicker._datepickerShowing) {
        if(inst.input.val() != inst.lastVal) {
            try {
                var date = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(jQuery.datepicker._get(inst, 'dateFormat'),
                                                       (inst.input ? inst.input.val() : null),
                                                       jQuery.datepicker._getFormatConfig(inst));
                if(date) { // only if valid
                    jQuery.datepicker._setDateFromField(inst);
                    jQuery.datepicker._updateAlternate(inst);
                    jQuery.datepicker._updateDatepicker(inst);
                }
            }
            catch (event) {
                jQuery.datepicker.log(event);
            }
        }
     }
      return true;
    }
 });
```

.......

Comment: Thanks Christian. More convenient (and less dirty!) way to change the function. +1